# Maven site command fails

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I'm trying to get maven site working, but I'm blocked on this error.

> [INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
>
> Failed to resolve artifact, possibly
>   due to a repository list that is not
>   appropriately equipped for this
>   artifact's metadata.
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:pom:2.6-SNAPSHOT
>
> from the specified remote
>   repositories:   sonar
>   (http://sonar:9000/deploy/maven),
>   central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
>   risk-idi
>   (http://nexus.yyy.com/nexus/content/groups/public-all)

I'm using maven 2.2.1 and maven site plugin version 2.2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what have you got so far, can you paste pom.. or some info .. we don't really see all in your monitor..

Comment: Please paste in or link the relevant sections of running maven with the `-e` flag

Comment: I figured out the issue. I should be specifying the plugin in reporting section to make mvn site work.http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-tries-to-download-wrong-pmd-version-td3327064.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found no  **maven-pmd-plugin-2.6-SNAPSHOT** in the official maven repository ([proof](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-pmd-plugin)). You can try to specify its version explicitly:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

Configuration is taken from [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: What if I do not need the pmd plugin report at all. When I run maven site. It needs it. why it is so?